# Showing a login screen as a modal view

Tags: iphone, ios, modalviewcontroller

I'm developing an app that can be used without logging in immediately, but certain tabs require login.  So I want to have my login view slide up whenever those tabs are opened.  If the user hits the Cancel button in the login view, the modal window should be dismissed and it should return to the same view the user was at before.  If the login is successful, the window should be dismissed and the tab should load.  What's the best way to implement this?  Should I make a custom tab bar controller?

EDIT: I took Caffeine's approach.  This seems to be working for me:

```
// App delegate

#pragma mark - UITabBarController delegate

- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController
          shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
  if ([[viewController topViewController] loginRequired]) {
    LoginViewController *loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
      initWithRootViewController:loginViewController];
    [tabBarController presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
    [loginViewController release];
    [navController release];
    return NO;
  } else {
    return YES;
  }
}
```

Comment: no, just check in your tab bar view whether you are logged in or not. if you aren't logged in, present your modal view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try implementing the `tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController` of `UITabBarControllerDelegate`. Present the modal login controller from within that delegate method and if it's successful return YES, otherwise NO.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make your tabBarController your `rootViewController`.
2. Create class and view for your `LoginController`.
3. In the first tab that would launch, (or the tab that you would require a modal view) go to the `viewDidLoad` method and reference `LoginViewController` and use

   ```
    LoginController *lvc = [[LoginController alloc]initWithNibName:@"LoginController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

        UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:LoginController];


    [self presentModalViewController:navController animated:NO];

     // This gives navigation control to the login controller //
   ```
4. If login is successful, you can just do `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`
5. If login is not successful, you can navigate go to a `ForgotLoginController` for password recovery or just `popToRootViewController` and go back to the previous screen or pop to the first view in the navigation stack and stay on the Login options.

Comment: Thanks, but that's what I have implemented right now and it doesn't work as I'd like.  "If the user hits the Cancel button in the login view, the modal window should be dismissed and it should return to the same view the user was at before. If the login is successful, the window should be dismissed and the tab should load."

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use TabBarController [delegate methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITabBarControllerDelegate) to detect tab changes, and then storing the selected index for later use.